# zsh: command not found: trianglectl on a Mac

Tags: macos, path, binary

i have download a binary file called trianglectl_darwin-amd64 on my MacBook with BigSur.
its a control tool thats work with K8s and get the idamToken what i need to work with kubectl in the next step.

$ sudo chmod 755 'trianglectl_darwin-amd64'
$ chmod +x ./trianglectl_darwin-amd64 
after this no error only next $

then when i type 
$ trianglectl login -e

i receive
zsh: command not found: trianglectl

i try a lot of thinks but can't get it run
i need help in this but please with details in the steps to do. So i do not miss anything.
Thanks

Comment: any one?  can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the file to `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` depending on the purpose of your program so that you can run it anywhere in the shell.

```
$ sudo cp ./trianglectl_darwin-amd64 /usr/local/bin
$ trianglectl login -e
```

Alternatively, you can run `./trianglectl_darwin-amd64 login -e` inside the directory where you put the binary file.

Comment: thats helps me thanks